# VkApi Исключение fields could not contain common_count for unauthorized user

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

При выполнении строки `Fields = VkNet.Enums.Filters.UsersFields.All` в

```
        var memders = vkClient.Groups.GetMembers(new GroupsGetMembersParams()
        {
            GroupId = config.GroupID.ToString(),
            Fields = VkNet.Enums.Filters.UsersFields.All
        });
        Console.WriteLine(memders[0].Activities);
        Console.WriteLine(memders[1].Id);
```

Вылетает исключение `One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: fields could not contain common_count for unauthorized user`

Я не вполне понимаю, что такое `common_count`, ибо, например, `Fields = VkNet.Enums.Filters.UsersFields.BirthDate` работает правильно.

Comment: Видимо вам надо либо явно перечислить нужные поля через `|` типа `UsersFields.City | UsersFields.BirthDate`, либо авторизоваться, потому что не все поля, перечисленные в `UsersFields` разрешены для запроса без авторизации.

Comment: @aepot что значит "авторизоваться"? AcsessToken я использую, а бот открыт в браузере. Вопрос про `All` скорее из интереса, ибо несколько полей я выбрать могу.

Comment: Поставьте курсор на `UserFields` и нажмите F12, увидите, что там за `All`.